# Why google-managed SSL certificate requires domain DNS to point to a static IP address instead of the load balancer itself?

Tags: ssl, dns, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm setting up the ingress for my GKE cluster, everything works but I think I'm missing something here.
The google tutorial states that we need to reserve an external static IP and add A record in our domain to point to such IP, then define both IP and certificate in the ingress rule.
Why can't we just point the domain to the load balancer IP?

Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs?hl=th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we have some misconceptions here. Let me explain a little bit more.

Your question shows nothing that you are using `nginx-ingress`. There is nothing besides a tag that is acknowledging it. Please update your question with information which controller you are actually using.

It's important because `gke-ingress` and `nginx-ingress` are 2 different resources. The guide that you are referencing is specific to `gke-ingress`. Annotations used there will not work with `nginx-ingress`. If you were following the guide step by step you used a `gke-ingress` and not `nginx-ingress`.

According to question in the title:

> Why google-managed SSL certificate requires domain DNS to point to a static IP address instead of the load balancer itself?

**The static IP address mentioned is a reserved resource and it's specifically created not to change.**

**This IP address will be used with a `Ingress` resource with your `GKE` cluster.** This will ensure that the `Ingress` resource will always have the same IP address and your domain will always point to it.

Deletion of your `Ingress` resource when it was created without a static ip address can lead to situation that a recreated `Ingress` will have a different IP address.

From above explanation: You can point with your domain name to an IP address that is no longer associated with your `Ingress` resource because your `Ingress` has another IP address.

GCP operate on 2 types of IP addresses:

- Ephemeral
- Static

Please take a look on official documentation about IP addresses on GCP: 
[Cloud.google.com: Compute: IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses)

Additionally there is an [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0) which shows the differences between service object of type `LoadBalancer` and `Ingress` resource.

Please let me know if you have any questions in that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I figured the same thing, defining ingress without specifying nginx class will create a gke ingress controller with load balancer and the google managed certificate only works with gke ingress controller. I end up using nginx with cert-manager for my application.